# Como criar máscaras em input com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar uma máscara para um input de telefone somente com JavaScript (não posso usar jQuery). Como posso fazer?

Comment: Pode usar jQuery?

Comment: Infelizmente não

Comment: Sei que muitos não concordam (em particular os "chefes" com seus requisitos)...  mas eu particularmente prefiro deixar o usuário fazer do jeito que quiser - essas máscaras são uma chatice para o usuário. Prefiro fazer validação e depois formatar o valor já validado.

Answer (score 5):

Aqui um exemplo, funciona com o 8 e 9 dígitos:

**Script:**

```
/* Máscaras ER */
    function mascara(o,f){
        v_obj=o
        v_fun=f
        setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
    }
    function execmascara(){
        v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
    }
    function mtel(v){
        v=v.replace(/D/g,"");             //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
        v=v.replace(/^(d{2})(d)/g,"($1) $2"); //Coloca parênteses em volta dos dois primeiros dígitos
        v=v.replace(/(d)(d{4})$/,"$1-$2");    //Coloca hífen entre o quarto e o quinto dígitos
        return v;
    }
    function id( el ){
        return document.getElementById( el );
    }
    window.onload = function(){
        id('telefone').onkeypress = function(){
            mascara( this, mtel );
        }
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" maxlength="15" />
```

**[DEMO](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/wp-content/uploads/legado/demos/js-dhtml/mascara-de-telefone-de-9-digitos-com-ddd-em-javascript/mascara-telefone-9-digitos.html)**

Fonte: http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/mascara-de-telefone-de-9-digitos-com-ddd-em-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Usando essa regex

```
^(\(11\) [9][0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4})|(\(1[2-9]\) [5-9][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|(\([2-9][1-9]\) [5-9][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})$
```

Essa regex aceita dois formatos de telefone

Formato do telefone aceito: *(99) 99999-9999* (este é compatível com o formato usado atualmente em São Paulo)

Outro formato aceito: *(99) 9999-9999* (este é compatível com todos os outros formatos do país)

Comment: Mas como eu coloco no input? Mostra o JS todo.

Answer (score 2):

Para os que podem usar jQuery, existe o [maskbrphone](https://github.com/masimao/maskbrphone), ele serve para mascarar telefones com oito e nove dígitos usando ou não o DDD. A sintaxe é bem simples, exemplo:

```
$('#telefone').maskbrphone()
```

Answer (score 2):

Usa expressão regular!

```
function mascararTel(v){
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");            
    v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g,"($1) $2"); 
    v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2");   
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script>
function mask(e, id, mask){
    var tecla=(window.event)?event.keyCode:e.which;   
    if((tecla>47 && tecla<58)){
        mascara(id, mask);
        return true;
    } 
    else{
        if (tecla==8 || tecla==0){
            mascara(id, mask);
            return true;
        } 
        else  return false;
    }
}
function mascara(id, mask){
    var i = id.value.length;
    var carac = mask.substring(i, i+1);
    var prox_char = mask.substring(i+1, i+2);
    if(i == 0 && carac != '#'){
        insereCaracter(id, carac);
        if(prox_char != '#')insereCaracter(id, prox_char);
    }
    else if(carac != '#'){
        insereCaracter(id, carac);
        if(prox_char != '#')insereCaracter(id, prox_char);
    }
    function insereCaracter(id, char){
        id.value += char;
    }
}
<script>

<!--CODIGO HTML-->
<input onkeypress="return mask(event, this, '(##) ####-####')" maxlength="14" placeholder=" (DDD) 0000-0000">

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Da seguinte maneira:

```js
var value = "11912345678"
var formatted = value.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d{4}).*/,"($1) $2-$3");
alert(formatted);
```

Answer (score -3):

Esta pergunta tem a resposta aqui:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650197/mask-javascript-variable-value

mais concretamente:

```
var input = document.getElementById( 'inputId' );

input.addEventListener( 'onchange', function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace( /\(|\)|-/g, '' ).replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4}).*/, '($1) $2-$3');
}, false );
```

Comment: Amigo, acho que você não entendeu a pergunta.

Comment: O problema foi mesmo estar a pensar em placeholders e ter-me esquecido completamente de masking no caso da formatação dos valores x'D